# Two functions I dont understand using the FileReader

Tags: javascript, html

I have problems understanding how `(function(theFile) { return function(e) {` works.

What does thefile do and if `e` is returned how can it be used as `e.target.result`?

Also what does the   `})(f);` do and why is it outside of the function.

```
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');

                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                    '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" id="', escape(theFile.name), '" onclick="_Element=this.id, RefreshElement()" /><br>'].join('');

                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: `function(theFile)` is actually a function closure. It is an anonymous function, that's created and called whenever the event fires. It returns a function that proper values when reader.onload is finally fired. Read more [here](http://blog.jbrantly.com/2010/04/creating-javascript-function-inside.html). Please ask if you want a formal answer with more explaining.

Comment: @François Wahl. The code is well explained with the comments and I was forced by SO to explain it. That doesn't make sense and it should be fixed. It's not very nice to give me -points because I showed you that bug. Also why did u delete your comment?

Comment: Ahh so its called closures. I've never seen that before and didn't know what it was. I've researched closures now and I understand it better. Your link was very usefull 2 Thanks a lot!

Comment: mind if I make a more formal answer? also, consider joining [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and discussing the various issues you think are wrong with SO (like the bug you think you found)

Comment: Sure u can answer more formally if u like and yea Ill join meta.

Comment: @Khez - I want a formal answer with more explaining!